# Can someone explain output of this C program?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    static int i = 5;

    if (--i)
    {
        main();
        printf("%d\n", i); // will this line executes ?
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
0
```

does code below main(); printf statement instructions is placed to stack  every time when main recursive calls happens and executed while terminated from this program?

Comment: This is basic recursion. I suggest you read up on it as well as how `static` works.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always show your current effort and tell us where **exactly** you have problems. If the output is not what you expect, tell us what you expect.

Comment: @DevSolar the site is supposed to build a searchable knowledge base that other people can use as a reference site ...  there is no way that a question titled "Can someone explain the output of this program" with no further text besides the code, will ever help anybody else

Comment: @M.M: This site is also supposed to help users with their problems; do we downvote questions because giving them a better title would have required knowledge that the OP *does not have* about the problem? If he'd known all about `static` and recursion, *he would not have had to ask*.

Comment: See [Why is "can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/303544#303544)

Comment: In fact, the question has been asked for exacly the same program at least 5 times already. I closed it as a duplicate to the oldest one that I found.

Answer (score 5):

`i` is reduced by successive calls to `main` until zero is reached.

*Then* `printf` is called for each level of recursion.

(Note that the behaviour of calling `main` from itself is well-defined although ill-advised in C, in C++ the behaviour is *undefined*.)

Comment: Calling `main()` is not undefined in C++.   Its usage is forbidden.

Comment: @Peter: U wot? A compiler does not have to issue a diagnostic.

Comment: @Bathesba - the actual wording in the 1998 C++ standard is "The function `main()` shall not be used (3.2) within a program".     In section 3.2, a function or object is said to be *used* if its name appears in a potentially evaluated expression.   There is no reference in any of that discussion to "no diagnostic required"  or to undefined behaviour - which means (Section 1.4) that it is a diagnosable rule.

Comment: @peter I think you should ask a question on the c++ tag on this.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (--i)
```

This will evaluate true the first time (`--i == 4`). The code recurses into `main()`. ([*Recursion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)): A function calling itself.)

As `i` is [*static*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/static_storage_duration), it will retain its value of `4` (as opposed to an automatic variable, which would be initialized to `5` again). The `if (--i)` in this *second* execution of `main()` will again be true (evaluating to `3`), and will again call `main()` (for a third execution of the function).

The same for `--i == 2` and `--i == 1`, for four executions of `main()` (including the first, non-recursive one) total that are evaluating the `if` condition to true.

The next recursion will evaluate the `if` condition to `--i == 0`, and thus false. Skipping the `if` clause, the function call will just return. *`i` is zero at this point, and -- being `static`, i.e. only one persistent `i` for all instances of `main()` -- will remain at that value.*

The `main()` call one level up the stack -- the one that evaluated `--i == 1`, then called `main()` and was waiting for it to return -- will now continue with the statement after the call to `main()`, and `printf()` the *current* value of `i`... which is `0`.

The same happens three more times (for a total of four) until the top-most `main()` returns. You get four times the current value of `i`, which is `0`.

---

Note that calling `main()` from your program is allowed in C, but not in C++. This is specifically for calling **`main()`** recursively; for other functions, it is allowed in either language.

Answer (score -2):

**(--i)** will decrease the value of i to 4 when it is called for the first time and it will continue the decrement of i until **(i==0)** due to recursion.
Since you have declared the variable i with static keyword and hence a single memory is allocated to it and all the changes are reflected back to it

Comment: if OP removes the `static`, it will be an infinite loop without output.

Comment: In what stage printf statement will execute..? Will these instructions in stack and executes while poping out from entire program?